# When I try to run my WEB Application I get this error

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

> 05-Jan-2016 23:44:35.610 SEVERE [http-apr-8080-exec-2] org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.doFilter An internal error occurred while trying to authenticate the user.
>
> org.springframework.security.authentication.InternalAuthenticationServiceException
>   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at dao.UserDAOImpl.getUser(UserDAOImpl.java:36)
>       at service.UserDetailsServiceImpl.loadUserByUsername(UserDetailsServiceImpl.java:38)
>       at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:102)

My web.xml

```
<display-name>Spring MVC Application</display-name>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-security.xml
        /WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml

    </param-value>

</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

security.xml

```
   <security:http auto-config="true"  >


          <security:intercept-url pattern="/admin-panel" access="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
          <security:intercept-url pattern="/user_panel" access= "ROLE_USER"/>


           <security:form-login login-page="/welcome"

                                default-target-url="/default"
                                username-parameter="username"
                                password-parameter="password"/>


   </security:http>



          <bean  class="service.UserDetailsServiceImpl" id="userDetailsService" autowire="byType">


   </bean>
   <security:authentication-manager  >
          <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService">


          </security:authentication-provider>
   </security:authentication-manager>
```

servlet.xml

```
<context:component-scan base-package="springapp.mvc,service,dao,domain"/>

<context:annotation-config/>


    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <mvc:default-servlet-handler />

    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="resources/">
    </mvc:resources>



<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>



    <bean id="template" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource">

        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource"
          class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">

        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/votingsystem"/>
        <property name="username" value="root"/>
        <property name="password" value="anl14anl14"/>
    </bean>
```

User.java

```
package domain;

public class User

{

    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String role;




    public User(String username, String password,String role ) 
    {

        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.role=role;

    }

    public User() {

    }

    public boolean enter(String username, String password) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        return true;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getRole() {
        return role;
    }

    public void setRole(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }
}
```

UserDAO.java

```
package dao;

import domain.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;

import java.util.List;


public interface UserDAO
{

    public User getUser(String username);


}
```

UserDAOImpl.java

```
package dao;

import domain.User;
import domain.UserMapper;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;





@Repository
public class UserDAOImpl implements UserDAO

{


    private JdbcTemplate template;

    private static final String find = "SELECT role FROM users WHERE username = ? ";

    public UserDAOImpl() {

    }

    @Override
    public User getUser(String username) {


        return template.queryForObject(find, new Object[]{username}, User.class);
    }


}
```

UserDetailsServiceImpl.java

```
package service;

import dao.UserDAO;
import domain.User;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;


@Service
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService

{

@Autowired
UserDAO userDAO;



    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username)

            throws UsernameNotFoundException


    {
        User user =  userDAO.getUser(username);

        Set<GrantedAuthority> roles = new HashSet();
        if (user.getRole().equals("admin"))
            roles.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN"));
        else if (user.getRole().equals("user"))
            roles.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));

      UserDetails userDetails =new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getUsername(),user.getPassword(),roles);
        return userDetails;


         }

    }
```

Controller.java

```
package springapp.mvc;

import dao.UserDAO;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

@Controller

public class HelloController
{



    @RequestMapping (value = "/welcome")


    public String get ( Model model )
    {

        return "welcome";
    }


        @RequestMapping (value = "/default")

        public String adminPage ( HttpServletRequest request) {

     if (request.isUserInRole("ROLE_ADMIN")) {

         return "redirect:/admin-panel";

     }

     else if (request.isUserInRole("ROLE_USER"))
     {
         return "redirect:/user_panel";
     }


    return "redirect:/welcome";
 }

    @RequestMapping (value = "/user_panel")

    public ModelAndView regPage ()
    {
        ModelAndView modelAndView  = new ModelAndView();
        modelAndView.setViewName("user_panel");
        return modelAndView;


    }

    @RequestMapping (value = "/admin-panel")

    public ModelAndView adminPage ()
    {
        ModelAndView modelAndView  = new ModelAndView();
        modelAndView.setViewName("admin-panel");
        return modelAndView;


    }
    }
```

welcome.jsp

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<html>

<head>
<title> Hello </title>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<c:url value="/resources/theme/css/main1.css" var="main"/>

    <link href="${main}" rel="stylesheet"/>



</head>

<body>



<div id="wrapper" >

<div id="header">

 <h1> ACCESS TO ELECTIONS  </h1>

</div>

    <div id="form_user">

    <div id="registration "> </div>



        <div class="form">
            <form method="post">
                <div class="youInfo">
                    <div class="info youName">
                        <label for="name">Name<input type="text" id="name" required /><span></span></label>



                        <label for="login">Login<input type="email" id="login" required /><span></span></label>
                        <label for="password1">Password<input type="password" id="password1" required /><span></span></label>

                        <button type="submit">Register</button>
                    </div>


             </div>
                </form>
        </div>

        <p id="part">  </p>

        <div id="enter"> </div>

        <div class="form">
            <form action="/j_spring_security_check" method="post"  >
                <div class="enter">
                    <div class="enterin">
                        <label for="username">Login<input type="text" name="username" id="username"/><span></span></label>
                        <label for="password">Password <input type="password" name="password" id="password"  /><span></span></label>

                        <button type="submit">Sign in</button>
                    </div>


                </div>
            </form>
        </div>

    </div>


    <div id ="footer"> </div>


    </div>




</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Which line UserDAOImpl.java:36 is?

Comment: @Abdelhak: Most likely the `return` line.

Comment: Because field `template` in `UserDAOImpl` is null (never assigned).

Comment: Friends , I have decided these problem . It was necessary to changeSQL script  "SELECT role FROM users WHERE username = ? "; to  "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ? " becouse wnen We use UserDetails userDetails =new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getUsername(),user.getPassword(),roles);
        return userDetails; it  reguires also "password "  and "roles" in this exaple

Answer (score 0):

You might be missing the `@Autowired` on `private JdbcTemplate template;` in UserDAOImpl.java.

```
@Repository
public class UserDAOImpl implements UserDAO {
    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate template;

    ...
}
```

Comment: Friends , I have decided these problem . It was necessary to changeSQL script "SELECT role FROM users WHERE username = ? "; to "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ? " becouse wnen We use UserDetails userDetails =new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getUsername(),user.getPa‌​ssword(),roles); return userDetails; it reguires also "password " and "roles" in this exaple